# Loading Barcode plugin in Phonegap using Plugman

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

Just starting up with PhoneGaps command line interface and it new Plugman command. Here are the calls I am making to create my project

```
Alex-Britez-MBP:barcodeApp abritez$ phonegap create /Users/abritez/Documents/Projects/phonegap/barcodeApp --name "barcodeApp" --id "com.company.barcodeApp"
```

With response

```
  phonegap  created project at /Users/abritez/Documents/Projects/phonegap/barcodeApp
```

I then attempt to load the plugin downloaded from (https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner)

```
 Alex-Britez-MBP:barcodeApp abritez$ plugman --platform ios --project /Users/abritez/Documents/Projects/phonegap/barcodeApp/platforms/ios --plugin /Users/abritez/Documents/Projects/phonegap/_plugins/barcodeReader
```

I get the following error on the terminal

```
grafting xml at selector "plugins" from "/Users/abritez/Documents/Projects/phonegap/barcodeApp/platforms/ios/barcodeApp/config.xml" during config install went bad :(
```

I checked the directory and it seemed like files where successfully added, but running the application fails in both Simulator and on device.

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

**Update:**
I did notice that in plugin.xml there was a line which stated

```
<config-file target="config.xml" parent="plugins">
            <plugin name="BarcodeScanner" value="CDVBarcodeScanner"/>
        </config-file>
```

I see 2 plugin folders one in cordova.plugin and the other on the top level. Curious if this is the issue.

Another interesting thing i noticed is how the directories where created by PlugMan. This doesn't seem like it is correct.

Screenshot here:
[image: Directory Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this issue, I solved it attaching `<plugins></plugins>` above `</widget>` in my `config.xml`. But this sounds as a temporary solution as `plugins` tag seems to be deprecated in new releases (to be confirmed, the documentation is really bad)...